# Most optimize way to load datas to display on router's controller

Tags: angularjs

I need to build a User that can be the resut of different REST API call (each way comes from a specific route).

Let's say for this example that we can visit:

- `http://myapp/#user/:pseudo`
- `http://myapp/#user/:user_id`

  ```
  angular.module('Test').config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider.
              when('/user/:pseudo', {
                  templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
                  controller: 'userFromPseudoCtrl'
              }).
              when('/user/:user_id', {
                  templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
                  controller: 'userFromIdCtrl'
              }).
              otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/'
              });
      }
  ]);
  ```

then, i have 3 different controllers:

- `userFromPseudoCtrl`
- `userFromIdCtrl`
- `userCtrl` (To control the view)

  ```
  angular.module('Test').controller('userFromPseudoCtrl', function($User, $http) {
      $http.get('/getUserFromPseudo/test')
      .success(function(User) {
           $User.set(User);
      });
  });

  angular.module('Test').controller('userFromIdCtrl', function($User, $http) {
      $http.get('/getUserFromId/test')
      .success(function(User) {
           $User.set(User);
      });
  });

  angular.module('Test').controller('userCtrl', function($scope, $User) {
      $scope.User = $User;
  });
  ```

This way is not good because the `userCtrl` is called before the $http callback (from the router's controllers), so the User is actually empty into the page (i was hopping it will be automatically updated).

Before i try to manage with it (using `$rootScope.$apply()`), i am wondering what is the more optimize way to do this kind of process (loading datas from router's controller then display it).

Do you use as many controllers as i do ? Do you process these REST APIs calls in the same controller that "bind" your view ? I am interesting to know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your routes you can define an additional value named `resolve` which is an object where each field is a promise that when resolved will be injected into your controller:

Route Definition:

```
when('/user/:pseudo', {
    templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
    controller: 'userFromPseudoCtrl'
    resolve: {dataNeeded: userPseudoService.getUserData()});
```

Service (**new**):

```
angular.module('Test').service('userPseudoService', function($http){
    return $http.get('/getUserFromPseudo/test');
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('Test').controller('userFromPseudoCtrl', function(dataNeeded){});
```

The route will not change until the promise is resolved.